# How to properly add examples to the R function that writes file

Tags: r, r-package

### What is the proper way to write documentation to the R function that is designed to write to the file?

#### According to the CRAN comments:

> Please ensure that your functions do not write by default or in your 
>   examples/vignettes/tests in the user's home filespace. That is not allow 
>   by CRAN policies. Please only write/save files if the user has specified 
>   a directory. In your examples/vignettes/tests you can write to tempdir()

#### Example:

Example below would use `tempdir()` function to generate the path

```r
tempdir()
> "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpiG8whL"
```

Will it be ok to submit package like that?

```r
#' @examples
#' x <- sd(1:10)
#' my_fun(x, path = tempdir())

my_fun <- function(x, path = "", file_n = "test"){
 file_p <- file.path(path, paste0(file_n, ".csv"))
 write.csv(x, file_p)
}
```

#### Example that would not do the test

or any function that writes the file should explicitly avoid testing examples?

```r
#' @examples
#' \donttest{ 
#' x <- sd(1:10)
#' my_fun(x, path = tempdir())
#' }

my_fun <- function(x, path = "", file_n = "test"){
 file_p <- file.path(path, paste0(file_n, ".csv"))
 write.csv(x, file_p)
}
```

### In addition, what is the best way to check for such problem?

Nothing should be created after running `devtools::check()` in the `tempdir()`, is this correct?

Comment: The best place to get solid answers to such questions is the package-devel mailing list. It doesn't appear that you are yet doing `R CMD check --as-cran`. That might be a place to start.

Comment: Both seem valid options to me.

Comment: apparently `tempdir()` is writing files in the temporary directory, `tempfile()` is ok

Answer (score 0):

For some reason function `tempdir()` keeps writing file in the temp directory

As a workaround I ended up using `tempfile()` in my examples. This keeps temp folder clean...

```r
#' @examples
#' x <- sd(1:10)
#' my_fun(x, path = tempfile())

my_fun <- function(x, path = "", file_n = "test"){
 file_p <- file.path(path, paste0(file_n, ".csv"))
 write.csv(x, file_p)
}
```